# Tengo problemas con los caracteres especiales en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Tengo una aplicación construida con asp.net core en donde uso react con redux pero tengo problemas en la visualización de algunos caracteres especiales.

Resulta que tengo un componente

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './media.css';

class Media extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s12 m3">
                    <div className="card">
                        <div className="card-image">
                            <img src="./images/covers/bitcoin.jpg" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-content">
                            <p>{this.props.title}</p>
                            <p>{this.props.author}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-action center-align">
                            <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#">Compartir</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Media;
```

Y en mi index.js tengo lo siguiente:

```
render(
<Media title="¿Qué es responsive Design?" author="autor"/>,
rootElement);
```

Desde aca le paso los datos dinamicamente a mi componente pero cuando se renderiza el texto me aparecen caracteres extraños.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi archivo index.html tengo las meta etiquetas del utf-8 pero aun asi tengo este error. Un dato importante a tener en cuenta es que cuando el texto lo coloco directamente en las etiquetas de mi componente este funciona bien y no tengo problemas con los caracteres especiales.

Quien me podria ayudar u orientar sobre este tema...?

Comment: Tiene toda la pinta de que el archivo tiene las meta etiquetas para decir que es UTF-8, pero en realidad está en otro formato

Comment: Si efectivamente esta en otro formato, ya que tube que solucionarlo guardando el archivo nuevamente en formato utf-8 pero no es la solucion definitiva ya que deberia hacer esto mismo archivo por archivo ...

Comment: Con qué IDE trabajas? Debe haber forma de configurarlo para que siempre grabe en urf-8

Comment: @PabloLozano Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 1):

estuve investigando un poco..... aparte de usar la codificación en utf-8 lo que esta sucediendo es que JavaScript posee una codificación adicional para esos caracteres especiales
intenta:

```
render(
<Media title="\u00bfQu\u00e9 es responsive Design?" author="autor"/>,
rootElement);
```

https://www.indalcasa.com/programacion/html/tabla-de-codificaciones-de-caracteres-entre-ansi-utf-8-javascript-html/

Comment: No es que JavaScript _posea una codificación adicional_ necesariamente: son _caracteres Unicode_.

Answer (score 0):

Si se esta usando visual studio, puedes añadir un archivo .editorconfig con

```
[*]
charset = utf-8
```

Puede ser que el editor este guardando en otro formato o tu plantilla lo este.